# Add background overlay (over a background image) that is fixed when scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I have a page that has a background picture that works fine on scroll, but I also want to add a semi-transparent overlay.

I have tried to do this by wrapping the background in a span container. The problem is that it's a page that users can add to, and when there is enough content that the user needs to scroll, the transparent background only covers the first page.

I've tried background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover;  but none of them work.

You see where the overlay stops [in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDVIM.jpg)

Relevant CSS:

```
body {

background-image: url(images/ocoast.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
}
.totalqs {

background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
color: white;
text-align: center;
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

PHP page, test.php

```
<html>
<head><title>All Questions</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css">
</head>

<span class ="totalqs"><body>
      <center><div class="navbar"><a href= 'ask.php'>Ask a Question</a>
      &nbsp;
        <a href='test.php'>Answer a Question</a>
        &nbsp;

       <a href= 'search.html'>Search</a>
       &nbsp;

       <a href= 'yourqs.php'>Your Questions</a>
       &nbsp;
       <a href= 'index.html'>Log out</a>

    <hr><hr></center>
    <br />    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

    <h1><u>Every Question Ever Asked</u></h1>      

    <p><u><b>Hello <?php echo $username; ?> Answer Another Users Question: </u></b><br><br /></p>

    <?php  
    /* 
    Get the questions from the database here and display them - 
    removed from question because its not relevant to the problem
    */
    ?>

    <br /><br />

    </body></span>
</html>
```

What can I do to make the overlay fill the whole background?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help

Comment: Try this background: url('images/ocoast.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; and add background-size: cover. If this still did not fix your problem then you might want to check if your image is for a full size page and if so then try setting the top and left to 0px and min-width and min-height to 100%.

Comment: thanks @TheGaME  but the background image is not the problem,  it works perfectly.  It's this line "background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);". from the totalqs class.   I had to add an opacity overlay in order to be able to read the links on the page better,  but when I scroll it only covers the first page.

Comment: @FluffyKitten  Hi thank you.  Yes I understand and I know this is a lot of code but the think is my <span> tag covers my whole test.php page so if I left anything out it might not make sense to everyone.  This is a lot of code in a problem though,  and I realize this.

Comment: It would be more helpful if we could see a working version. Can you create a working Code Snippet with the HTML that's generated that recreates the issue? See [How to create a runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @Dylano236. Did you trying adding the class to body instead of span? Hope <span> should be child of body and not parent.

Comment: @TheGaME I did just try to put the span tag inside the body but did not do anything.  The reason I cant have the body hold all this is because some pages on the site don't need/cant have the overlay background.  I appreciate the help though.  I'd give you a point if I could!

Comment: @FluffyKitten  thanks I try to work on something.  Yes I wish you could see it because it is a hard problem to explain!

Comment: @Dylano236. Is it possible to provide screenshots of what you want to achieve? May be that might help in providing valuable suggestions.

Comment: Sure I'll do that now.

Comment: @TheGaME  alreaight I've added a screenshot.  It's a link in the question.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @Dylano236.. can you create a Chat room and we can share code in that before i post my answer?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have enough reputation to do that :(

Comment: @Dylano236.. can you check for this room PHP background overlay and join the chat?

Comment: @TheGaME Ok I need to figure out how to join a chat room now.  Give me a min.

Comment: Go here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms and search for the room "PHP background overlay" and click on it.

Comment: @TheGaME  Man I found the room but they wont let me in.  It's alright,  post what you got and I'll give you the answer.  I know you're trying hard!

Comment: I think I can read what you post in there though so just try to post some things.

Comment: They say I need 20 reputation to chat

Comment: @TheGaME yes I see your chat message

Comment: @TheGaME I got your code in the chat room.  That's great thanks!  I have to log off for a couple hours right now but will be back and can work on it and do the jfiddle thing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see now that the problem you are having is getting the element with the transparent overlay to fill the screen.

Instead of using a separate element, you can **add a transparent overlay on the body element itself** by faking it with a gradient [Ref: CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/tinted-images-multiple-backgrounds/), e.g.

```
body {
    background: 
        /* top: transparent grey, faked with gradient */
        linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), 
        /* bottom: image */
        url(images/ocoast.jpg)  no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This does away with the need for a separate element altogether. You can apply the other  styles (e.g. `color: white`) directly the body, or you can create a `<div class="container">` element (inside the `<body>`!) if you prefer.

**Working snippet** - I made the overlay green, so it was obvious that it was covering the whole area):

```css
body {
  /* BACKGROUND */
  background: /* top: transparent colour, faked with gradient */
  linear-gradient( rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)), /* bottom: image */
  url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a11js.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;

  /* CONTENT */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}


/* for testing only: add big vertical margin to make page scroll */
p { margin: 100px 0; }
```

```html
<body class="backimg">

    <div class="navbar"><a href='ask.php'>Ask a Question</a> &nbsp;
      <a href='test.php'>Answer a Question</a> &nbsp;
      <a href='search.html'>Search</a> &nbsp;
      <a href='yourqs.php'>Your Questions</a> &nbsp;
      <a href='index.html'>Log out</a>
    </div>

    <hr><hr>

    <p>TEST</p><p>TEST</p><p>TEST</p><p>TEST</p>
    <p>TEST</p><p>TEST</p><p>TEST</p><p>TEST</p>

</body>
```

**NOTE:** FYI Your HTML is not valid - you can't have any elements outside the `<body>` tags. Also `<center>` is deprecated, its not causing the problem but you should change it anyway - use the `text-align: center` style instead.

**UPDATE**

**Add overlay to specific pages only, or had different colours one each page**

If you want to add an overlay to specific pages, you can do this in the same way but using classes. You could also do this to add different colours to different pages if you wanted!

1. Add the CSS to the class instead of the `<body>` element
2. In your HTML, add a class to the body element

Then add the corresponding class to the `<body>` of each page! So for example:

**1. CSS**

Create CSS classes for each different background you want to use:

```
/* This will only contain the CSS that applies to all pages, e.g. */
body{text-align: center;}

/* Set up the different classes you will use, e.g. these are for green and blue overlays: */
body.greenoverlay{
  background: /* top: transparent colour, faked with gradient */
      linear-gradient( rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)), /* bottom: image */
      url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a11js.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}

body.blueoverlay{
  background: /* top: transparent colour, faked with gradient */
      linear-gradient( rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.3)), /* bottom: image */
      url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a11js.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}
```

**2. HTML**

Add the right class to the body of each page, do for example:

- No overlay: `<body>`
- Green overlay: `<body class="green-overlay">`
- Blue overlay:  `<body class="blue-overlay">`

FYI, because we are using `linear-gradient` to fake a solid background colour, you can create all sorts of gradient and colour effects. Run this snippet to see what I mean (I don't suggest you use it! but it shows the what you can do):

```css
body.rainbowoverlay {
  background: /* top: transparent colour, faked with gradient */
  linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 50, 50, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 50, 50, 0.5) 1%, rgba(255, 248, 50, 0.5) 35%, rgba(71, 255, 50, 0.5) 56%, rgba(137, 163, 255, 0.5) 79%, rgba(237, 137, 255, 0.5) 100%), /* bottom: image */
  url(http://oi67.tinypic.com/28a11js.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body class="rainbowoverlay">
    <p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p>
    <p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p><p>z</p>
</body>
```

You can use this gradient generator to generate the CSS for the `linear-gradient` in your CSS:
http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ff3232+1,fff832+35,47ff32+56,89a3ff+79,ed89ff+100&0.5+0,0.5

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  I like that green color too!  The reason I was not going to put it in the body was because some pages I did not want to have the overlay,  like my index page but if I can get a color like this I'll do it on every body.  I'm giving you the answer!  I feel bad because TheGaME helped e a lot to but what can I do.  Thanks!!

Comment: @Dylano236 Glad I could help! You can make it any colour you like, just change the RGB values in the rgba() calls. If you only want to add the overlay in specific pages, you can easily do that using classes... I'll update my answer to show you how. Also, don't worry about TheGaME - you wouldn't have been able to accept their answer because they didn't actually add one :) You can't accept a comment, so they will understand! People here can often help in the comments if we don't fully understand the problem, or if we don't have a proper answer.

Comment: Just saw this.  Thanks for the help!